# Using multiple callbacks in form validation in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am separating the logic of defining form validation rules into a library. i want to apply multiple callback functions on a single form element.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'callback_db_check|callback_valid_email');
```

Now i don't know how to do this. Because its not working i mean multiple callback are not working. But if i define single callback its working fine.

```
function db_check(){
    $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('db_check', 'Not found in db');
}

function valid_email(){
    $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('db_check', 'Invalid email');
}
```

This is just example code. I have extended form validation library so that i can define and call validation logic from my library . Any suggestion how i can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('email' , 'Email' , 'required|valid_email|max_length[255]|callback_email|callback_call_db');
```

p.s. your callback should always return true or false (your example doesnt return anything)

Comment: OK yes returning true or false on each function is working fine thanks but the syntex is liek this i have $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('email'   , 'Email'   , 'required|valid_email|max_length[255]|callback_email|callback_call_db');

Answer (score 3):

You can apply multiple callback functions in a single element

Validation rule can be set by using the format

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'callback_db_check|callback_valid_email');`

and the callback functions must return true or false  .

```
function db_check($user) 
     {

        $sql=$this->db->query("select * from user where email like '%$user%' ");
        if($sql->num_rows()>0)
        {
             return true;
        }
             else
        {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('db_check', 'Not found in db');
        return FALSE;
        }

     }




 function valid_email($user) 
      {


            if(//condition)
            {
                 return true;
            }
                      else
            {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'In valid email');
            return FALSE;
            }

      }
```

In user side

```
<div class="field_main">
<div class="fi_title">E-Mail Address *:</div>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"  value="<? echo set_value('email');?>" class="field_class" />
<? echo form_error('email','<div class="error">', '</div>');?>
</div>
```